# COM Method Result is not showing correct value

Tags: com, asp-classic, vbscript

I have the following method call in my COM component. This method is called from VBScript.

```
STDMETHODIMP CMyInterface::TestX(VARIANT* myTest)
{
    myTest->vt = VT_I4;
    myTest->lVal = m_nCount;
    ++m_nCount;
    return S_OK;
}
```

The following code is used to invoke the method. But the last statement `'    Response.Write("Value of result" & result)'`is not printing **0**. *What could be the problem?*

```
Set myObject = CreateObject("MyCom.MyInterface")
result=myObject.TestX(value)
Response.Write("Value of result" & result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scripting clients don't consider the HRESULT to be the return value of a method call. Instead, they look for a parameter marked in the IDL as [out, retval] and use that as the return value.